# Download file from Autodesk Forge 3D viewer

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do I download a file from the 3D viewer in Autodesk Forge. I am using 2 legged authorization and I am able to upload files to the bucket, but I am not sure how to download the file from them in the 3D viewer. The code below downloads files but there is nothing contained inside them:

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', '#');
element.setAttribute('download', node.text);
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

I have looked at this link as a reference but I don't understand how to convert this into code inside Javascript or .NET: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/

Comment: This tutorial you are referencing is to download files from BIM 360 Docs, not from your OSS Bucket storage. Let me understand a bit better why do you need to download files from the Buckets? Usually the use of the buckets is to later on request the translation of the CAD file for the use of the Forge Viewer which is not the original CAD format anymore, it will be an SVF (JSON Strings) for the visualization in the Viewer.

Comment: Sorry I am still learning how to use Autodesk Forge and I created a button to upload items into a bucket, so I wanted to create a button to download the same item but if it isn't possible then I will try to implement it in my BIM 360 version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to download files now, from Javascript use `$.ajax` with the `url` path to the method in .NET then use:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri address = new Uri(storageLocation);
fileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\" + fileName;
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + credentials.TokenInternal);
client.DownloadFileAsync(address, fileName);
return client;
```

This will download files to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this endpoint:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-GET/

It will download an object from the Bucket location you specify.

This is a REST endpoint you can check both the NPM or NuGet we have to see if that function is already available. In case is not please submit a request to be include it.

Comment: I am trying to download from BIM 360 documents and have linked Javascript and C# to try and download an item from a folder, but when using the code:
`client.DownloadFileAsync(storageLocation, fileName);`, I get error 500 and I'm not sure why.